# Different output from auto.arima when parallelization is enabled

Tags: r, statistics

The information outputted by auto.arima() when enabling parallelization seems to differ from that outputted when not using parallelization. Specifically, when parallelization is enabled, the output does not specify the values of `p`, `d`, and `q` nor report the AICc or BIC information criteria.

Example without parallelization:

```
> model <- auto.arima(ts,xreg=tax.ts,ic=c("bic"),stepwise=FALSE,approximation=FALSE)
Series: ts 
ARIMA(0,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ma1      tax
      0.4589  -0.7035
s.e.  0.0806   0.6969

sigma^2 estimated as 0.6028:  log likelihood=-138.36
AIC=282.72   AICc=282.92   BIC=291.08
```

With paralellization:

```
> model <- auto.arima(ts,xreg=tax.ts,ic=c("bic"),stepwise=FALSE,approximation=FALSE,parallel=TRUE,num.cores=12)

Call:
auto.arima(x = structure(list(rwhitebread = c(89.2749786376953, 89.2966079711914, 
88.9023666381836, 88.6773300170898, 89.0641860961914, 89.6114883422852, 89.5789642333984, 
89.3341522216797, 89.0179290771484, 88.4036026000977, 88.309211730957, 87.6592483520508, 
87.3339614868164, 87.2614440917969, 87.7638092041016, 87.3240356445312, 88.6289749145508, 
90.0923461914062, 90.2542266845703, 90.6454772949219, 90.7220764160156, 90.4558944702148, 
90.8726654052734, 91.7483978271484, 92.7035140991211, 92.5734100341797, 92.4802780151367, 
92.6397476196289, 93.3086471557617, 92.8956298828125, 92.6798477172852, 94.3108444213867, 
96.7846298217773, 99.8294296264648, 100.150718688965, 103.013710021973, 103.426765441895, 
102.606864929199, 102.679161071777, 103.586181640625, 106.069953918457, 105.177772521973, 
104.857940673828, 104.737091064453, 104.414154052734, 103.719192504883, 101.936988830566, 
101.443199157715, 101.572723388672, 101.843193054199, 101.829467773438, 101.567581176758, 
102.02978515625, 101.891319274902, 101.730346679688, 101.729293823242, 101.258888244629, 
100.753799438477, 100.468338012695, 100.157859802246, 99.6511154174805, 99.5886764526367, 
98.7140121459961, 98.9120025634766, 99.6159439086914, 100.186874389648, 99.477912902832, 
99.2161636352539, 99.1324768066406, 99.4329071044922, 99.8656692504883, 100.098243713379, 
100.050888061523, 100.484085083008, 100.259925842285, 101.157867431641, 102.265960693359, 
102.379020690918, 102.103042602539, 102.0927734375, 101.972709655762, 101.002868652344, 
99.5803604125977, 99.2621994018555, 100.411376953125, 101.165588378906, 101.440376281738, 
101.992752075195, 102.306083679199, 102.090476989746, 101.909233093262, 105.202362060547, 
108.684272766113, 108.776985168457, 108.79345703125, 108.924339294434, 108.688865661621, 
108.240608215332, 107.647567749023, 106.971420288086, 107.167625427246, 106.995262145996, 
107.178039550781, 107.176040649414, 106.977165222168, 106.254096984863, 104.939926147461, 
104.52613067627, 104.082489013672, 104.322189331055, 103.974395751953, 104.827789306641, 
105.576438903809, 105.718490600586, 105.364852905273, 105.030937194824, 104.75341796875, 
103.981002807617, 103.218376159668, 102.868370056152, 102.812316894531)), .Names = "rwhitebread", row.names = c(NA, 
-121L), class = "data.frame"), ic = c("bic"), stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE, 
    xreg = tax.ts, parallel = TRUE, num.cores = 12)

Coefficients:
         ma1      tax
      0.4589  -0.7035
s.e.  0.0806   0.6969

sigma^2 estimated as 0.6028:  log likelihood = -138.36,  aic = 282.72
```

Is there any way to get the same output from the parallelized command, or otherwise extract the parameters used in the model and the AICc/BIC?

Comment: You need to turn `approximation` `TRUE`.

Comment: @Pascal Thanks, that indeed works, though the models change slightly. I still wish I understood why `approximation=FALSE` generates the desired output without parallelization but not with...